# Android Studio Open JDK Error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, java-8, java

i have set cache size to 10000 while i was working on android studio and restarted it ,now im not able to start it
i have replaced studio.vmoptions and studio64.vmoptions which are not making any difference
i tried reseting java versions by sudo update-alternatives --config java
but that too failed
where can i find the options and reset the file so that i can work on android studio

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;
>   support was removed in 8.0 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring
>   option MaxPermSize=10000m; support was removed in 8.0 Invalid
>   ReservedCodeCacheSize=10000M. Must be at most 2048M. Error: Could not
>   create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has
>   occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you have updated Android Studio or have another `*.vmoptions` which is overriding the setting you have applied. Run the following command to search for all locations of the config file.

`sudo find / -name *.vmoptions`

You may see that you have multiple defined. You should not modify the `vmoptions` contained in the Android Studio install directory. You should only modify the version that is in your home directory under the version of Android Studio you are running.

So for example with Android Studio 2.2 the file would be located at `~/.AndroidStudio2.2/studio64.vmoptions` or `~/.AndroidStudio2.2/studio.vmoptions` depending on the architecture you have installed.

You can safely delete any configurations for older version of studio and make sure to check both the global and current version `vmoptions` to see if you have conflicting settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an error on the installation so the best is to uninstall it and also the jdk and install them again